# Extract branch name from p4 depot path

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, p4python

Is there any perforce command or p4 util available to extract the branch name out of depot path.
For ex I have depot location as "//depot/folder/suffix" and the branch name as "b-folder-suffix".
How do I get the branch name from the depot? Is it possible to get that kind of mapping?

Note: I am not looking for RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tiny Perl script that does that without using any regexes:

```
foreach(`p4 -F %domainName% branches`) {
    chomp;
    if (`p4 -F %code0% populate -fn -b $_ -s $ARGV[0]` != 554768862) { print $_."\n"; }
}
```

Sample output (where each branch maps `//depot/main` but only `foo` maps `//depot/foo`):

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 branches
Branch bar 2020/03/16 'Created by Samwise. '
Branch foo 2020/03/16 'Created by Samwise. '
Branch spaces 2020/03/16 'Created by Samwise. '

C:\Perforce\test>perl get-branch.pl //depot/foo/bleh
foo

C:\Perforce\test>perl get-branch.pl //depot/main/bleh
bar
foo
spaces
```

It works by running a `populate` command over each branch spec with the specified file path, and looking for the specific error message `no source file(s) in branch view` (which is error code 554768862; I got this by playing around with `p4 -e populate ...`).  If it *doesn't* get that message it assumes the path is mapped by the branch view.  Note that this script as written is not robust in the face of other errors (e.g. permissions).